# How to use XQuery in Oracle to get specific data

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, xquery

I have an **XML** like the following:

```
<configurations>
  <config>
    <pop3server>pop.gmail.com</pop3server> 
    <userid>abc_aa</userid>
    <proxyport>12</proxyport>
    <capturetomailonly>False</capturetomailonly>
  </config>
</configurations>
```

I would like to retrieve the data between the angular brackets i.e **pop.gmail.com** from

```
<pop3server>pop.gmail.com</pop3server> or
```

12 from

```
<proxyport>12</proxyport>
```

in **ORACLE**.

Tried it using the below way but could not get results.

```
CAST(CAST(ConfigXml AS XML).query('data(/configurations/config/pop3server)') AS NVARCHAR2 (64))  Pop3Server
```

How to go forward with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `EXTRACTVALUE` function as follows:

```
SQL> select EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype('<configurations>
  2    <config>
  3      <pop3server>pop.gmail.com</pop3server>
  4      <userid>abc_aa</userid>
  5      <proxyport>12</proxyport>
  6      <capturetomailonly>False</capturetomailonly>
  7    </config>
  8  </configurations>'),'/configurations/config/pop3server') from dual;

EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE('<CONFIGURATIONS><CONFIG><POP3SERVER>POP.GMAIL.COM</POP3SER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pop.gmail.com

SQL>
```

`xmltype` is used to convert the string to xmltype datatype.